# Redirect to Subcategory and Subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i want redirect "viewdownload" and "viewcategory" category to subcategory and sub domain and remove .html

example:

```
site.com/viewdownload/all category/all pages.html
redirect to
subdomain.site.com/download/viewdownload/all category/all pages

and

site.com/viewcategory/all pages.html
redirect to
subdomain.site.com/download/viewcategory/all pages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two rules should achieve what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^viewdownload/all_category/(.*).html$  http://subdomain.site.com/download/viewdownload/all_category/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^viewcategory/all_category/(.*).html$  http://subdomain.site.com/download/viewdownload/all_category/$1 [R=301,L]
```